# How can I export all the Appointments in .ics file using EWS?

Tags: c#, winforms, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2007

I am using EWS to manage operations of Exchange Server email accounts. How can I export all the Appointments of calendar in the .ics file?
I have tried by following.

```
string iCalFileName = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "appointments.ics");
foreach (Appointment appointment in service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, new ItemView(int.MaxValue)))
{
    appointment.Load();
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(iCalFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        using (StreamWriter s = new StreamWriter(fs))
        {
            s.WriteLine(appointment.MimeContent.Content);//error must load property before using it
        }
    }
}
```

Can anybody suggest me what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MimeContent (and a number of other properties) aren't returned when you use FindItem you need to make a separate GetItem call on each item to retrieve that. The best thing to do is use LoadPropertiesFromItems which will batch the GetItem request in the Managed API see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2010/03/16/loading-properties-for-multiple-items-with-one-call-to-exchange-web-services.aspx

Cheers
Glen

Comment: I want to export all the appointment in ics file same like gmail. I have tried by above but I am not getting success. I have tried by https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn672317(v=exchg.150).aspx. I have tried your solution too. Can you please suggest me link or example which help me to export all the appointment/meetings in ics file?

Comment: I would suggest you publish the calendar first http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2014/04/15/how-to-publish-anonymous-calendar-sharing-url-in-exchange-online-or-exchange-2013.aspx then you can just get that Ical Feed like gmail.